# Android volley JsonArrayRequest in the service

Tags: rest, android-service, android-volley

I am using JsonArrayRequest in the android service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
    //...
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, "", new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.i("SUCCESS", response.toString());
                    stopSelf(startId);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    stopSelf(startId);

                }
            });
    CORE.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
    Log.i("StationsService", "onStartCommand END");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

After run I get Exception on stopSelf(startId);:

```
java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
        at com.omsk.wwtlf.istanbultransportnet.api.services.StationsService$1.onResponse(StationsService.java:42)
        at com.omsk.wwtlf.istanbultransportnet.api.services.StationsService$1.onResponse(StationsService.java:36)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Could you advise a proper way to stop service from Volley?

Answer (score 0):

pass jsonarray as request not "" (blank string)

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, final int startId) {
//...
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, <jsonarray-object>, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.i("SUCCESS", response.toString());
                stopSelf(startId);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                stopSelf(startId);

            }
        });
CORE.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
Log.i("StationsService", "onStartCommand END");
return START_STICKY;
```

}

Comment: I removed this parameter from constructor, JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                (Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>....
Exception is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("name", "value");
    return params;
}
then make new constructor :
public PostJsonArrayRequest(String url, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, null, listener, errorListener);
}
```